# node.js - How to adjust the the stdout buffer size (aka highWaterMark) of child_process.spawn()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to adjust the buffer size (highWaterMark) for the `stdout` from a child_process.spawn() call, and I'm having a hard time doing this successfully. Below is some code that illustrates what I'm looking for. I'm trying to perform some benchmarking with various stdout buffer sizes, but until I can actually adjust the buffer size, I won't be able to do so. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

```
// I'm using the `stdout` from a child_process.spawn() call to feed into another stream, and I'm having a hard time increasing the buffer size on stdout.
// The code below illustrates the issue:
const child_process = require('child_process');
const stream = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');

const compressStream = child_process.spawn("cat", ["testfile_32MB"], {writableHighWaterMark: 1024*1024, highWaterMark: 1024*1024});  // <-- child_process.spawn does not have highWaterMark or writableHighWaterMark options, so including them has no effect, but I'm including it just as an illustration of what I want.
compressStream.stdout.writableLength = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout._writableState.writableLength = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout._writableState.writableHighWaterMark = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout.writableHighWaterMark = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout._readableState.highWaterMark = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout._writableState.highWaterMark = 1024*1024; // <-- This does not help.
compressStream.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log("data length [from spawn()]:", data.length); // <-- data.length will always be <= 64KB! How can we get it higher?
});

const readStream = fs.createReadStream("testfile_32MB", {highWaterMark: 1024*1024});
readStream.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log("data length [from createReadStream()]:", data.length); // <-- This prints values <= 1MB, which is what I wish I had for child_process.spawn/stdout...
});
```

Note, you'll need a file called "testfile_32MB" in place to run this example code, and it should be at least a few megabytes in size.

Comment: It appears that [`spawn` does create a socket for `stdout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/child_process.js), and for that you should set [`compressStream.stdout.writableLength`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writablewritablelength)

Comment: Hi @Bergi Thanks. I gave that a try, but unfortunately it did not favorably change the result in the example code above. Perhaps I'm not applying the setting correctly, but I've tried many different ways of doing it. If you find a way to apply in such a way that it actually changes the output, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, you cannot do this. `highWaterMark` is a mechanism that is used to signal the writer to stop because the reader is not reading and its buffer is full.

A `Socket` will send you the data as soon as it is available. It will always use an internal hard-coded 64k buffer. Increasing the `highWaterMark` will make it capable of holding more data, but it will still send you 64Kb chunks - except that you will get bursts of several calls per event loop rotation.

You don't have access to the `Stream` creation options when using `spawn` - you can eventually pass a preconstructed named pipe stream - but this won't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a limitation that ideally shouldn't exist. I'll open a github issue on the node.js project

Comment: @Andrew Does this issue have any progress? Did you open github issue or find a solution for this case? Please, let me know if you have something

Comment: @AlexandrKostrov the issue was carried on here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41611

Comment: Unfortunately despite the nice efforts of @mmomtchev it doesn't appear there's been much progress in terms of getting a patch merged